# Initial value problem with null surface data

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, reference-request, general-relativity, semi-riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a $d$-dimensional Lorentzian manifold, i.e., the metric tensor $g$ has signature $(-1,+1,\dots,+1)$ where $-1$ appears only once and $+1$ appears $(d-1)$ times.

A null hypersurface $\Sigma\subset M$ is one codimension one embedded submanifold whose normal vector $n$ is null, i.e., $$g(n,n)=0.$$

On the other hand a spacelike hypersurface $\Sigma\subset M$ is one codimension one embedded submanifold whose normal vector $n$ is timelike, $$g(n,n)<0.$$

Now, further suppose that $\Sigma$ is *globally hyperbolic* so that a Cauchy surface can be defined and an initial value problem can be defined. In that sense, there is a theorem stating what is the appropriate initial value on a spacelike hypersurface. This is presented in Wald's General Relativity as:

> Theorem 10.1.2: Let $(M,g)$ be a globally hyperbolic spacetime (or a globally hyperbolic region of an arbitrary spacetime) and let $\nabla$ be any derivative operator. Let $\Sigma$ be a smooth, spacelike Cauchy surface. Consider the system of $n$ linear equations for $n$ unknown functions $\phi_1,\dots \phi_n$ of the form $$g^{ab}\nabla_a\nabla_b\phi_i + \sum_j (A_{ij})^a\nabla_a \phi_j + \sum_j B_{ij}\phi_j + C_i = 0\tag{10.1.20}.$$ Then equation (10.1.20) has a well posed initial value formulation on $\Sigma$. More precisely, given arbitrary smooth initial data, $(\phi_i,n^a\nabla_a \phi_i)$ for $i=1,\dots,n$ on $\Sigma$ there exists a unique solution of equation (10.1.20) throughout $M$. Furthermore, the solutions depend continuously on the initial data in the sense described above for the Klein-Gordon equation in flat spacetime. Finally a variation of the initial data outside of a closed subset, $S$, of $\Sigma$ does not affect the solution in $D(S)$ [the domain of dependence].

This tells that given appropriate initial value on a spacelike Cauchy surface, namely, the value of the fields and their first derivatives along the normal, we are granted a unique solution.

[This paper](https://cds.cern.ch/record/289282/files/9510049.pdf) alludes to such a result when $\Sigma$ is a null surface, but: (1) it just talks about a single scalar field, (2) it never precisely states a theorem and (3) it is not much rigorous really. The claim is on page 14:

> We emphasize that **the initial value data needed for the null surface development consists of the function on a pair of null surfaces**; it is not the same as the data needed in the standard Cauchy problem, which is the function and its first time derivative on an initial surface [14], [15].

I've tried skimming through the papers [14] and [15] mentioned there, but they never even mention null/lightlike surfaces, so if the result is there it is probably phrased differently and I wasn't able to identify it.

**My question**: is there one analogue theorem of Theorem (10.1.2) for *null surfaces*? In other words, a theorem stating what is the appropriate initial value data to be specified on null surfaces to find a unique solution of an equation like (10.1.20)? My particular interest would be in null infinity $\mathscr{I}^\pm$ defined in the Penrose completion of an asymptotically flat spacetime, but I believe such theorem would just care about the surface being null.

References are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

For a single null surface, the existence/uniqueness theorem is not possible. This follows from the consideration in the *linear* case where if you try to solve the linear wave or Klein-Gordon equation 
$$ \partial^2_{tt} \phi - \triangle \phi + m^2 \phi = 0 $$
with initial data prescribed along $\{ t = x^1\}$. You easily see that for some initial data no solution exists, while for others infinitely many solutions exist.

---

In terms of an actual existence and uniqueness theorem when you have more than just a single null surface, quite a bit is known (even in the quasilinear case) rigorously.

- In the case of a pair of transversely intersecting null hypersurfaces, the characteristic initial value problem was studied in great detail by Alan Rendall https://www.jstor.org/stable/51794?seq=1 ; with many further developments by other authors. See also http://www.numdam.org/item/AIHPA_1990__53_2_159_0/
- In the case of a singular null hypersurface (think of the hypersurface as the light cone emanating from a point), results can be found due to Hormander https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022123690901299?via%3Dihub , Cagnac https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01762134 and others.

I am however pretty sure that the case of data prescribed at general $\mathscr{I}^\pm$ are more delicate, since you are looking at scattering data. (Note that for general AF space-times, the domain of dependence of $\mathscr{I}^\pm$ can in fact be quite small (think any black hole space-time); in those cases existence and uniqueness of solutions from scattering data alone is certainly not true.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is called the characteristic Cauchy problem, and it consists of giving initial data on two null and transverse hypersurfaces. See for instance https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.15267